# Questions on column spaces

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

The following are some true false questions that are homework problems. I have stated both the answer and the reason.
1. If the columns of a matrix are dependent, so are the rows. (True as row rank=column rank).
2. The column space of a $2*2$ matrix is same as its row space. (True as they are square).
3. The column space of a $2*2$ matrix has the same dimension as its row space. (True. r=m=n, the number of pivots is same in both cases).
4. The columns of a matrix are a basis for the column space. (False. Not always. Only linearly independent columns that span the column space forms a basis).

Comment: 1. is false: $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \cr 1 \end{pmatrix}$ has independent columns, but dependent rows.

Comment: 2) What is the column space of $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$?  What about the row space?  (*this is of course assuming that you think of the vector $[a,b]$ in the same way as the vector $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$ in the first place.  If you want to be pedantic, the rowspace consists of row-vectors while the column space consists of column-vectors and thus could never be equal*)

Comment: 1. So the only $1\times n$ matrix is the null matrix?